# Make Sphinx 3 ignore repeat words / keyword spam

Tags: php, sphinx

I have inherited a very old PHP web app that uses Sphinx v2.2 for freetext search (indexing columns in a MySQL table, querying via PHP API).

Since Sphinx 2.* is outdated, I have upgraded to Sphinx 3.1 and now use SphinxQL via MySQL instead of PHP API.

Everything works more or less as it should, except in Sphinx 3 search results with repeat words are given unexpected extra weight/relevance.

The index configuration (sphinx.conf) is identical between version 2 and 3. 
Analyzing the old Sphinx 2 code shows nothing special, it appears to use most of the defaults.
I tried all the available Sphinx 3 rankers (PROXIMITY_BM25 etc) but none provide the desired result.

```
## sphinx.conf
## same for v2.* and v3.*

source products {
    type = mysql
    sql_host = *****
    sql_user = *****
    sql_pass = *****
    sql_db = stock
    sql_port = 3306

    sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
    sql_query_pre = SET collation_connection = utf8_general_ci

    sql_query = SELECT p.product_id, p.stock_tag, p.cat_number, p.cat_number_clean , p.product_name, \
    p.clean_name, p.supplier_id, p.availability, p.product_group, s.supplier_weight, \
    s.name, product_group.product_group_id, product_group.group_name \
    FROM product AS p INNER JOIN supplier s ON p.supplier_id = s.supplier_id \
    INNER JOIN product_group ON p.product_group = product_group.group_code \
    WHERE p.availability = 'OK' AND s.active = 1

    sql_attr_string = product_group
    sql_attr_uint = supplier_weight
    sql_attr_multi = uint key_id from query; SELECT product_id, key_id FROM product_attribute

    sql_ranged_throttle = 0
}
index products {
    source = products
    path = /var/lib/sphinx/products
    mlock = 0
    morphology = none
    min_word_len = 1
    ignore_chars = U+002D,U+00AD,U+2011,U+2013,U+2014,U+2015,\,(,),U+002E
    min_infix_len = 2
    html_strip = 0
}
```

```php
// sphinx 2 query (PHP)

$sph->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, "@relevance DESC, supplier_weight ASC");
$sph->Query('"workbench"/3 | (@cat_number_clean *workbench*) | (@clean_name "workbench") | (@stock_tag *workbench*)');
```

```sql
-- sphinx 3 query (SphinxQL)

SELECT *, WEIGHT() FROM products WHERE
MATCH('"workbench"/3 | (@cat_number_clean *workbench*) | (@clean_name workbench) | (@stock_tag *workbench*)')
ORDER BY WEIGHT() DESC, supplier_weight ASC LIMIT 50
OPTION field_weights = (cat_number_clean=999,clean_name=1,stock_tag=1)
FACET key_id ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 0, 25
```

Sphinx 2 query simply acts as if the repeat words weren't there.

For example, in a search for "workbench" Sphinx 2 would rank "automotive mechanics workbench" and "workbench automotive workbench mechanics workbench" about the same, whereas Sphinx 3 gives much more weight to the result with repeated words (keyword spam attempt).

NB. I have no control over word repetition in the source product names, they come like that from the suppliers and mustn't be altered.

Answer (score 0):

fixed by downgrading from Sphinx 3.1.1 to 3.0.3 and full re-index